# Meaning of "I'm just getting to the good part"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, jokes

Can someone explain me this joke?

[image]

I think, I can't understand phrase - "I'm just getting to the good part".

Comment: You know ? the set of numbers is a length of circle over length of diameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a protest, sometimes sarcastic, that means that the person speaking is about to get to the part of their joke or story that is funny, interesting, etc.