# Comprehension of just getting to the bit where

Tags: reading-comprehension

> We were in the playground acting out Vending Machine Mum the other day and **just getting to the bit where** she's making my bed while I'm completely not helping at all.

This is some in cartoon. I want to comprehend the bold part : Can we replace the bold part with '*being sorry because*' ?

cf [Meaning of "I'm just getting to the good part"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73563/meaning-of-im-just-getting-to-the-good-part)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, 'just getting to the bit' refers to a particular point in a series of things. You could be baking bread, and just getting to the bit where you're putting it in the oven. You could be driving a car home and just getting to the bit where you're turning into your driveway. It doesn't have anything to do with sorrow, or regrets.

Comment: ...and is usually used of stories or other narratives (as here).

Comment: I've heard it used in normal conversation, often enough that it doesn't sound strange to me. "I was just getting to the point where I was going to say something, but he left"

Comment: Agree, but in my variety of English 'bit' would be used with narratives and 'point' with either narratives or real life.